# Jmeter unable to receive a new cookie

Tags: testing, cookies, jmeter, automated-tests, jmeter-4.0

I encounter a problem that Jmeter couldn't get the latest cookie from the http request. 
There are 3 webs:

- Main page: it responds the initial cookie
- Login page: it requests with the initial cookie from 'Main page', and responds a new cookie
- Search page: it requests with the new cookie from 'Login page', and responds with correct result

Now the problem is:

- Main page: requests and responds well
- Login page:　requests with the initial cookie, get the right response body, but couldn't get the 'set-cookie' in the response header (detailed in the structure)
- Search page: requests with the initial cookie, doesn't get the expected response

The structure is:

- -Thread
- --HTTP Request Defaults: Protocol=https, and input the server name
- --HTTP Cookie Manager: 1. 'Login page' receives the 'set-cookie' in the response header while the Policy is rfc2965, but the 'Search
  page' request becomes 'no cookies'; 2. 'Login page' can't receives
  the 'set-cookie' in the response header while the Policy is not
  rfc2965 (all the others), 'Search page' requests with initial cookie
- --HTTP Request for Home page
- --HTTP Request for login page with HTTP Header Manager
- --HTTP Request for search page with HTTP Header Manager
- --View Results Tree

The jmeter version is 4.0.

How can I run the script for Search Page correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try switching "Policy" to [`netscape`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2109) - this is the less restrictive
2. Try adding the next line to [*user.properties*](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#miscellaneous) file:

   ```
   CookieManager.check.cookies=false
   ```

   JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up

If it doesn't help:

3. [Increase JMeter log verbosity for the HTTP Cookie Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file

   ```
   <Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control" level="debug" />
   ```

   and look into *jmeter.log* file for any suspicious entries
4. Add the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   CookieManager.save.cookies=true
   ```

   this way JMeter will be storing cookies into JMeter Variables in form of `${COOKIE_yourCookieName}` - this way you will be able to manually add cookies to "Search" page request
5. In any case you can extract the values from [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) header using i.e. [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) and either add [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) header via [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) or provide the cookie in another HTTP Cookie Manager (place it as a child of the "Search" request)

Comment: Thank you very much Dmitri. Step 1 & 2 works! 'Search page' responds the expected body, though I can't see the 'set-cookie' in the response hearder and it uses the initial cookie to send the request. It seems the keypoint is about "CookieManager.check.cookies=false" comparing with the original version.